# How to round float number? C++/CLI - VS2015

Tags: floating-point, c++-cli, rounding, precision, visual-c++-2015

Suppose there are two float numbers: **a, b**. I need to assign value of **a** to **b**. Then **b** would be converted to a text string by a function, which I can not change. Convertion is done by taking first 3 decimal digits of a float number **without** rounding, other points are ignored. This leads to loss of accuracy.

Question: how can I change value of **a** so, that then after convertion **b** would be like if it was rounded?

Hope that I managed to explain problem, but if didn`t, please, tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that these function use "truncate": 1.2346 => 1.234, right?

You can add 0.0005

```
b = a + 0.0005
```

Example:

Round to lower

```
a = 1.2341;
b = a + 0.0005; // 1.2346
string result = yourfunction(b); // 1.234
```

Round to upper

```
a = 1.2346;
b = a + 0.0005; // 1.2351
string result = yourfunction(b); // 1.235
```